# Small web page with Python

Tags: python-2.7, bottle

I have created a small wiki page with Bottle: Python web framework. Every thing is working fine right now. You create a article by going to "Create a new article" and giving it a Title and write down some Text. Then all of the created article shows on the index page in a list, and you can click on them to open and read.

But the thing is when i click on the article with the purpose to edit the article by giving it a new title and add some new words to the text. It doesn't change the name on the orginal textfile, instead i get a new textfile with the new title and the orginal textfile still remains.

This is the code:

```
from bottle import route, run, template, request, static_file
from os import listdir
import sys
host='localhost'

@route('/static/<filname>')

def serce_static(filname):
    return static_file(filname, root="static")

@route("/")
def list_articles():
    '''
    This is the home page, which shows a list of links to all articles
    in the wiki.
    '''
    files = listdir("wiki")
    articles = []

    for i in files:
        lista = i.split('.')
        word = lista[0]
        lista1 = word.split('/')
        articles.append(lista1[0])

    return template("index", articles=articles)


@route('/wiki/<article>',)
def show_article(article):
    '''
    Displays the user´s text for the user
    '''
    wikifile = open('wiki/' + article + '.txt', 'r')
    text = wikifile.read()
    wikifile.close()

    return template('page', title = article, text = text)


@route('/edit/')
def edit_form(): 
    '''
    Shows a form which allows the user to input a title and content
    for an article. This form should be sent via POST to /update/.
    '''
    return template('edit')

@route('/update/', method='POST')
def update_article():
    '''
    Receives page title and contents from a form, and creates/updates a
    text file for that page.
    '''
    title = request.forms.title
    text = request.forms.text
    tx = open('wiki/' + title + '.txt', 'w')
    tx.write(text)
    tx.close()
    return template('thanks', title=title, text=text)



run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True, reloader=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The article object is too simple to list, edit or update.

1. The article should have an **ID** as its file name.
2. The article file should have two fields: title and text.

   For example: 10022.txt

   ```
   title:
   bottle
   text:
   Bottle is a fast, simple and lightweight WSGI micro web-framework for Python.
   ```
3. You should retrieve the article by ID.
4. You can open the file by ID and change its title and text.